# Implement vibration and sound settings in a local notification in my iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, audio, vibration

I have a UILabel named "Notifiction Sound". On its tap gesture I want to open a list of default alert tones of iOS device. On selection of any one of these alert tones, the selected alert tone should be set as my local notification sound. How to implement this?

Also, I want to add vibration on/off settings for local notification. I successfully checked if vibration UISwitch is on/off. When switch is on I used following code to set vibration on. Tested this on iPhone, but it did not work. Any idea how to implement it?

And does sound and vibration together work for local notification?

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice].model isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])
{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);   
}
else
{
    // Not an iPhone, so doesn't have vibrate
    // play the less annoying tick noise or one of your own
    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is still for iOS 7.1 and below, you could easily do this with a UIActionSheet.

if you're wanting to do actions based upon selection of this item though, i'd suggest using a UIButton, as such: (Note: this is for doing it in code)

```
- (void) actionMethod
{
   UIActionSheet *action = [[UIActionSheet alloc]...];
   // set action delegate

   // the delegate method is where you want to check 
   // what option you want to do and all the other stuff
}

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
   UIButton *b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   b.frame = ...;
   [b setTitle:@"Notification Sound" ...];
   [b addTarget:self selector:@selector(actionMethod) ...];
   [self.view addSubview:b];
}
```

that should basically put you on the right track. I do not believe programming is done right until you learn it on your own. So, go here to check out apple's documentation

[UIActionSheet documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiactionsheet_class/Reference/Reference.html)